# Сократить(оптимизировать) код для вывода массива

Tags: java

Можно ли сделать более разумно и красиво данный код?:

```
        int[] numbers = {3,4,2,7};
        int sum = 10;
        System.out.print("[");
        for(int i = 0; i<numbers.length - 1; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print(numbers[numbers.length-1]);
        System.out.print("], " + sum + " -> ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, воспользуйтесь методом toString класса Arrays

```
        int[] numbers = {3,4,2,7};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Выход:

```
[3, 4, 2, 7]
```

Comment: Испытываю чувство стыда за свою глупость...